# Up-to-date repository for CentOS git RPMS

Tags: centos, yum, git, rpm

I'm currently maintaining git packages manually for my CentOS machines since there seem to be no recent packages available in the Repos. I'm rebuilding the SRPMS from kernel.org, but `--without docs` since I can't satisfy the dependencies, which is not pleasant.

A recent query on the mailing list yielded a single result - a personal repository, which is not enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[webtatic](http://www.webtatic.com/blog/2009/09/git-1-6-4-on-centos-5/) appears to have a repo with version 1.6.5.2 as of this posting.

Answer (score 2):

The ultimate repository is [Dag Wieers](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/)'. He has been building RPMs for thousands of projects for some time now, and is one of the first things I [add to my repos.d dir](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/FAQ.php#B). It was rebranded as RPMForge a couple of years ago, which involved merging with a couple of other widely-respected repositories.

He has [Git rpms](http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/git/) in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Those RPMs are quite old, in the 1.5.x range. I'll looking for up-to-date ones, in the 1.6.x - preferrably 1.6.3 - range.

Comment: As of June 2010 or so, RPMforge has had very recent versions of git.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem.  The way I solved it was by following the INSTALL instructions in 1.6.5.1.  Near the bottom, it explains how to grab a copy of the pre-formatted documentation.  It's pre-built, and you can get it once you've installed git.  The commands are as follows:

```
$ mkdir manual && cd manual
$ git init
$ git fetch-pack git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git man html |
  while read a b
  do
    echo $a >.git/$b
  done
$ cp .git/refs/heads/man .git/refs/heads/master
$ git checkout
```

I actually needed another command:

```
git reset --hard
```

...but after that, it worked like a charm.  I just added that directory to my `$MANPATH` in my ~/.bashrc like this:

```
# git man pages
export MANPATH="$HOME/local/git-manual:$MANPATH"
```

...and all the man pages work as expected.  I am so happy that I got this after upgrading!  Hope it works for you too...

Answer (score 1):

How recent?  [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) has 1.5.5.6: http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/git.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm looking for up-to-date ones, in the 1.6.x - preferrably 1.6.3 - range.

Answer (score 1):

Given how greatly you value having recent package versions, Centos probably isn't the distro you're looking for.  Even Fedora Rawhide does not have git 1.6.3, largely owing to the fact that it was just released 2 weeks ago. I did find it in the Gentoo ~arch tree, as well as an ebuild that will build off the current git HEAD.

Comment: There’s a slight difference between valuing having recent package versions and not wanting to use packages that are 6 years old or worse.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest Git RPMs directly from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/RPMS/). However, you might run into library dependency issues on CentOS, due to older versions of dev libraries available there. The last time I looked into Git on CentOS 5.x, the latest version I could reliably install from RPM was 1.5.6.1. Newer versions, you're probably better off compiling the SRPMs, or compiling the Git source directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As my questions says, I'm rebuilding the SRPMS from kernel.org, but --without docs since I can't satisfy the dependencies. I'm looking for a proper repo for them.

Comment: I'd venture to guess there isn't a public repo of newer Git versions. RHEL/CentOS 5 is getting long in the teeth, and to stay current with a lot of software you'll need to roll your own anyway. I would certainly automate the build process and post the RPMs on a local yum repository.

Comment: Not my ideal answer, but this is the harsh reality. Thanks.